# Failing to approximate π(x) using sieve method

Tags: approximation, sieve-theory

So I was playing with Eratosthenes sieve when I noticed a pattern in the number of primes less than n. I start of with n numbers then I remove multiples of 2 (1/2 of all numbers) then I remove all multiples of 3 (1/3 of the remaining numbers) and so on for all primes less than √n. I figured that if I pretend to sieve n numbers I would have a fast way of approximating π(x).

Here is the pseudocode of my implementation.

```
def count_primes n
    for p in sieve √n
        n -= n/p
    return n
```

I then tested counting up to 1000.

```
count_primes 1000
=> 157
```

The true number of primes < 1000 is 168. So I'm getting an underestimation wich makes sense since when I'm removing multiples of 2 I'm also removing the prime number 2. This is further supported by the fact that I'm off by 11 wich is the number of primes < √1000. I thought that this approximation would get better as n → ∞ because √n becomes insignificant.

I then tested counting up to 10^16.

```
count_primes 10^16
=> 304,797,218,820,068
```

This is an overestimation of about 9%, how is this even possible? It is not rounding errors since switching to floating point has negligable effects on the result. After a bit more testing I found that the overestimation starts at 35005 and gradually gets worse from there. That means it can't be the square root function since it has 15 digit precision.

Any way I try to reason around this I should be subtracting at least 1 more number than I would in an actual sieve. Am I missing something? Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: When you remove the numbers divisible by 2, you indeed remove about n/2 numbers. But then when you remove the numbers divisible by 3, you don't remove n/3 numbers because a certain proportion of the numbers divisible by 3 was already previously removed for being even. The ones you double count are exactly the numbers divisible by 2 and 3, i.e. divisible by 6. So when you do the step for $p=3$ you actually remove about n/3 - n/6 numbers. This kind of logic continues on for higher primes.

Comment: I don't get it, if I have 100 numbers I remove even ones. I now have 50 left, then I remove 1/3 of those since every 3rd number is a multiple of 3 this rounds to 16 removed. Then I remove 1/5 of the remaining 34 rounds to 6 removed. now I have 28 and and remove 1/7 or 4 leaving me with 24 according to my algorithm. Wich is what I get when I run it. I've done this out on paper up to n = 10,000 and it produces what I'd expect. At every step I'm just removing the multiples of a prime from the numbers not already gone. If were computing n-n/2-n/3-n/5-n/7 for n = 100 I'd have 100-117 or -17 numbers